# PHP how to fetch row value by unique value is passed

Tags: php, mysql

For my website I am generating unique value **email** and **random code** as **login**, so when the user login with the above email and code, so I need to echo the details of that user only.

Example:
In my database im having first name, last name, mobile number, email, code.
So if the user login with email and code, I have to Echo all details as first name, last name, mobile number

In my case how to use exact query to echo all the details by email and code.

```
$sql = 'select firstname, lastname, mobileno from clients where code=; & email=
If (is_array($row = $db->queryRow($sql))) 
Echo($firstname, $lastname, $mobileno) = $row;
```

Please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 $code = $_POST['code'];
 $email = $_POST['email'];

$sql = $db->prepare("SELECT firstname, lastname, mobileno FROM `clients` WHERE code = ? AND email = ?");
$sql->execute(array($code, $email));
 $results = $sql->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

 foreach ($results as $row) {

  echo $row['firstname'].'<br>';
  echo $row['lastname'].'<br>';
 echo $row['mobileno'].'<br>';

 }
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the html to login:

```
<form action="" method="POST">
<input name="email" type="email"><br>
<input name="code" type="text"><br>
<input name="submit" type="submit" value="login">
</form>
```

This will be different for each user as he has his own details to login...

Submitting the form:

```
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {

$email = $_POST['email'];
$code = $_POST['code'];

    $sql = mysql_query("SELECT firstname, lastname, mobileno FROM `clients` WHERE code = '$code' AND email = '$email'");

    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql)) {

    echo $row['firstname'].'<br>';
    echo $row['lastname'].'<br>';
    echo $row['mobileno'].'<br>';

    }
}
```

Comment: As the MySQL extension is officially deprecated and due to be removed from PHP before the end of this year, an answer using MySQLi or PDO with a prepared statement and bind variables would have been a better answer.... especially as the `email` and `code` values are likely to be coming from user input

Comment: True, but yet he now has a start on how to write his queries.

Comment: @JeroenBellemans thanks for the help, The random code and email        $code = 'ASDYBU';
$email = 'xxxxx@zz.com'; will changes by user by user so its not static one, so need a query that works for all users

Comment: I've made a simple login form, where `$email` and `$code` are dynamic. It'll be different for each user as he has his own details to login.